# Extjs model array of string mapping

Tags: javascript, extjs

It seems to be very basic question, but happens to kill lot of my time.

How can I map following in to `Ext.data.Model`?

```xml
<Principal>STEMMED CORP.</Principal>
<BusinessDefinitions>
    <value>NY CLIENTS CORE</value>
    <value>US LISTED DERIVS- STOCK,ADR,ETF</value>
    <value>US CLIENT SITE TRADING</value>
    <value>SYNDICATES - ADRS AND CBS</value>
    <value>GWM CAPITAL MARKETS</value>
</BusinessDefinitions>
<countryOfResidence>USA</countryOfResidence>
```

Problem is, I unable to figure out how to get array of string for `BusinessDefinitions` against each value.

The following field is what I have added to `Model.fields`:

```js
// Business Definition(s)
{
    name: 'BusinessDefinitions',
    type: 'auto',
    mapping: 'value',
    convert: function(n, record) {
        console.log('BusinessDefinition: ' + n);
        return n;
    }                       
}
```

I have tried other combinations as well, but nothing seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried using JSON instead of XML as your data provider?

Comment: Wish I could.! But, I am supporting older service which only outputs XML

Comment: What I need is, model should contain property named 'BusinessDefinitions' of type array(of string). here array contains each 'value' as string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following was fabricated to fit your data from the example below.

Here is a [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/j59) of the answer I have provided. It is *4.2.1.883* compliant. I have yet to try this with version *5.1.0*.

### Data

```xml
<BusinessArray>
    <BusinessItem>
        <Principal>STEMMED CORP.</Principal>
        <BusinessDefinitions>
            <value>NY CLIENTS CORE</value>
            <value>US LISTED DERIVS- STOCK,ADR,ETF</value>
            <value>US CLIENT SITE TRADING</value>
            <value>SYNDICATES - ADRS AND CBS</value>
            <value>GWM CAPITAL MARKETS</value>
        </BusinessDefinitions>
        <countryOfResidence>USA</countryOfResidence>
    </BusinessItem>
</BusinessArray>
```

### Application

```js
Ext.define('App.model.Business', {
    requires: [ 'Ext.data.reader.Xml' ],
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'principal',
        mapping: 'Principal',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'country',
        mapping: 'countryOfResidence',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'businessDefs',
        type : 'auto',
        convert: function(value, record) {
            var nodes = record.raw.querySelectorAll('BusinessDefinitions value');
            var items = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                items.push(nodes[i].textContent);
            }
            return items;
        }
    }] 
});
```

```js
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
    launch : function() {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'App.model.Business',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'business.xml',
                reader: {
                    type: 'xml',
                    record: 'BusinessItem'
                }
            },
            autoLoad : true
        });
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title : 'XML Model Example',
            layout : 'hbox',
            items : [{
                xtype: 'combo',
                fieldLabel: 'Business',
                emptyText: 'select',
                editable: false,
                queryMode: 'local',
                store: store,
                displayField: 'principal',
                valueField: 'businessDefs',
                listeners : {
                    select: function (combo, record, index) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Business Definitions', combo.getValue().join('<br />'));
                    }
                }
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

---

## Example

The example below is from the accepted solution from [Sencha Forums: How do I parse a XML node to an array of strings? Also handing XML attributes?](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?229794-How-do-I-parse-a-XML-node-to-an-array-of-strings-Also-handing-XML-attributes).

### XML Data

```xml
<jobs>
    <job>
        <id>1</id>
        <name audioSrc="audio/jobs/names/electrician.mp3">Electrician</name>
        <attributes>
            <attributeID>sitting</attributeID>
            <attributeID>individual</attributeID>
            <attributeID>lightEquip</attributeID>
            <attributeID>doer</attributeID>
            <attributeID>physical</attributeID>
            <attributeID>repair</attributeID>
        </attributes>
    </job>
</jobs>
```

### Store

```js
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'App.model.JobData',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: dataURL,
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'job'
        }
    }        
});
```

### Model

```js
Ext.define('App.model.JobData', {
    requires: [ 'Ext.data.reader.Xml' ],
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [{
            name: 'id',
            mapping: 'id',
            type: 'int'
        }, {
            name: 'title',
            mapping: 'name',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'attributeList',
            mapping : 'attributes',
            convert: function(value, record) {
                var nodes = record.raw.querySelectorAll('attributes attributeID');
                var arrayItem = [];
                var l = nodes.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    var node = nodes[i];
                    arrayItem.push(nodes[i].textContent);
                    console.log(nodes[i].textContent);
                }
                return arrayItem;
            }
        }] 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.! Got proper direction with it.

Answer (score 0):

Following is what worked for me:
No need to add  `requires: [ 'Ext.data.reader.Xml' ],`
With that, following is the final field

```
},{
            //Business Definition/s
            name: 'BusinessDefinitions',
            type: 'auto',
            mapping: function(data){
                return data.children[2].children[10];
            },          
            convert: function(value, record) {
                var items = [];
                var nodes = record.data.BusinessDefinitions.querySelectorAll('BusinessDefinitions value');

                for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                    items.push(nodes[i].textContent);
                }
                return items;
            }                   
        },
```

Comment: Yeah, the requires was just an oversight. It was modeled after the example at the end of my post. It is harmless and just serves as a reminder that this model is to be paired with an XML reader since it is modeling XML data coming in.