# Model array of string mapping in Extjs6

Tags: arrays, extjs, model, mapping

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858953/extjs-model-array-of-string-mapping) we have example of code. My problem is very similar and my question is how can I do the same in extjs6?

We do not have 'raw' field in 'record' anymore in extjs6. I've tried different things from forums but I still don't understand how to do it. Also I found nothing about arrays mapping in sencha docs or extjs6 forum; maybe I have to use manyToOne relations in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out for myself, it looks strange but it works...

```
Ext.define('App.model.Report', {
requires: ['Ext.data.reader.Xml','Ext.data.soap.Reader', 'App.model.Value'],
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    {name: 'Name', mapping: 'Name', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'Caption', mapping: 'Caption', type: 'string'}
    {name: 'Comment',   type: 'auto',
    convert: function(value, record) {
        var nodes = Ext.getStore('reportsStore').getProxy().getReader().rawData.querySelectorAll('Comment Value');  
        var arrayItem = [];
        var l = nodes.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            var node = nodes[i];
            arrayItem.push(nodes[i].textContent);
        };
        return arrayItem;
    }
    }]
});
```

And now i have a new problem, i can't get my 'Value' for one 'Comment' block, only for whole SOAP response, i have found nothing useful in docs, and i think maybe manyToOne relations could be useful here? but i do not understand how i should configure proxy and reader for my 'many' model. Sorry for my English.